# Assigning a number to an Object... Strangely, but this piece of code runs in Java

Tags: java

Assigning a number to an Object... Strangely, but this piece of code runs in Java:

```
Object a="123abc";
System.out.println("a="+a);


Object b=123;
System.out.println("b="+b);
```

The result being:

```
a=123abc  
b=123
```

Could you please explain why and how it works?

Comment: You have to distinguish between variables, objects, and references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to expand on @Juned's answer, based on @Art's comment *"it's still not obvious for me. b's type is still - Object, right?"*

In your code:

```
Object a = "123abc";
System.out.println("a=" + a);

Object b = 123;
System.out.println("b=" + b);
```

`123abc` is an object of Class `String` — this String happens to be defined as a constant value at compile time.

`a` is a variable which is a reference to an object of class `Object` ***or any** compatible sub-class*.

It is similar to doing this:

```
Object a;
String s = new String("123abc"); // very redundant way to make a String
a = s;
```

The variable String `s` can be assigned to the variable Object `a` because String is-a subclass of Object; `Object a` can reference *any* kind of Object including all subclasses.

The same applies to `Object b` except that `123` is a primitive `integer` constant. But when assigning that to an object, it is *auto-boxed* as Juned mentioned, like doing `Object b = new Integer(123);`

Again, an Integer is a subclass of Object, so the assignment is legal.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign a child object to a parent reference.

```
Parent p = childObj; // is perfectly valid
```

When you do

```
Object b=123;
```

`123` is converted to an `Integer` object because of auto boxing and reference is assigned to `b`. And

```
System.out.println("b="+b);
```

prints `b=123` because `println` method calls `toString` method of passed object, in your case Integer b.toString is called and hence the output.

Comment: Thank you! But it's still not obvious for me. b's type is still - Object, right? How come that I can refer to its integer value simply by using it as in integer variable - whereas - and it's obvious - that I can't write "b.intValue()"? Is it some sort of the compiler magic covered by that notorious autoboxing?

Comment: @Art Because you can only call methods while are available on the reference. As your reference is of type Object so you will only have Object class methods available. You cannot call b.intValue() because that belongs to Integer class. If you change the reference to type Integer you will be able to call its methods.